# Why is my Java application running incorrectly on Linux and not Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows

Sort of a vague question, but here we go:

I have a Java application that performs 100% as it should on Windows, however, when uploaded to a server running Linux, the application still runs, just incorrectly. I know it's not file paths or file names, but what are some key difference between windows and linux that could cause an application to act haywire on one or the other?

I don't want a direct answer to my problem, (hence not posting the code or what the application is doing) I'm just more interested in what might cause issues like this and haven't been able to find a list anywhere.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you do not tell at least what your application is doing, anything said will just be wild guesses. Also, you do not even tell how it fails.

Comment: I get that you want a list of potential differences, but I still think some more specifics in your question will help you get a better list and a better answers.   As it stands, without specifics, I don't have anything to prompt my brain to think through the differences.

Comment: UDP scans. Windows doesn't put rate limits on ICMP (port unreachable messages to be precise). Linux does. Did I get the ball rolling? :p

Comment: In general, Java is "write once - run anywhere".  It should not behave differently between systems, except where OS interfaces differ somewhow.

Comment: Threading: Thread.sleep() has a lower granularity at windows (~16ms)  compared to linux.

Answer (score 2):

Mismatched file paths (i.e., `C:\\Users\\` instead of `/tmp`).  The file delimiter difference often breaks programs that hard code it instead of loading it dynamically.

Also, anything run with `exec()`, as the commands to be executed will be different.

Your post says "I know it's not file paths or file names", but without any sort of code or examples, this is pretty much the key error.  Java is designed to be platform-independent and the vast majority of code is not affected by the operating system, as the JVM will generate the appropriate bytecode for that machine.

Comment: Hm, I didn't think about exec(). I'll look into that. Thanks for the input.